# Apollo Android Client - Cannot access generated classes on classpath

Tags: java, android, android-studio, graphql, apollo-android

I've generated the Apollo  classes successfully and can see them in the build directory, however they're not available on the classpath. Strangely the Enum that is generated is available but the classes themselves aren't.

Running the sample project provided on Apollo's Github does work but I cant see the difference between the configurations.

mcve below.

https://github.com/michaeljq/graphQlMCVE

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to edit or reference `build/generated` source code?

Comment: I'm not trying to edit it, I'm trying to access the generated class. As in import the class.

Comment: Your `app/build.gradle` isn't compiling that as a dependency. I don't think you can import plugins within your code (at least I've never tried)

Comment: Um, that doesn't look right. There should be package directories inside of `build/generated/source/apollo/`. What is the contents of your `src/main/graphql/` directory? If it is just the GraphQL document file directly, create a set of subdirectories matching your desired Java package for the generated code, and move the GraphQL file into there.

Comment: @CommonsWare BTW, https://github.com/michaeljq/graphQlMCVE/tree/master/app/src/main/graphql

Comment: @cricket_007: Yeah, I noticed that shortly after posting the comment, then was busy writing an answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right now, you have `src/main/graphql/` containing GraphQL documents. That means that your Java classes will be generated with no Java package, which probably is not what you want.

Instead, create a package tree under `src/main/graphql/` (e.g., `src/main/graphql/apollotest/mq/apollotest/api/`). Move the GraphQL documents and `schema.json` there. Clean the project, and you should find that your Apollo-generated classes are available to you in whatever Java package you chose (e.g., `apollotest.mq.apollotest.api` in the above example).

Comment: I did this but I still don't see the generated `.java` files in my project. I do see them in the `build/generated/source/apollo/mypackage` directory though. I still can't reference them from IDEA. What can be the problem?

Comment: @AdamArold: I don't use IDEA. Somehow, you need to teach it that `build/generated/source/apollo/` has sources to be included in your project.

Comment: I think it is better to copy them over to the `src/main/java` folder, or not?

Comment: Well, they will get regenerated when you change your GraphQL schema, your GraphQL queries, or upgrade Apollo-Android. So, IMHO, it is better to teach IDEA to pull from the generated source directory. Otherwise, you will forget to manually copy them again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenshot to understand the solution faster:
[image: Project structure]

Comment: this is an incorrect diagram and didn't worked for me. what commonsware said was to create subfolders similar to our current architecture hierarchy . [this folder system](https://imgur.com/AC0IKim)  worked for me

Comment: @Andrii-Kovalchuk : what if internal module(app in above img) is ant project and external prj(GraphQlAndroidInFull) is in gradle. How we should generate build folder inside internal module in this case. I am using apollo client 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had forgotten to include the package name in app level `build.gradle` file

```
apollo {
    // instruct the compiler to generate Kotlin models
    generateKotlinModels.set(true)
    packageNamesFromFilePaths("com.example.your_package_name")
}
```

After this I didn't need to create the subfolders inside `graphql` folder.