# Cannot resolve symbol on graphql generated class

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

I've been trying to use Apollo GraphQL with Android, following the steps [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started/).

I've managed to get to the point where the necessary files get auto-generated but after that is where I'm stuck. When I try to use the query I get a "Cannot resolve symbol" error. Is there a way I can access my query?

I've tried the suggestion here: 
[Apollo Android Client - Cannot access generated classes on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141835/apollo-android-client-cannot-access-generated-classes-on-classpath)
But the class files don't get auto-generated, also even if I import the project directory I still can't access the query.

Here's the code for my query:

```
query ReadUser($username: String!) {
    readuser(username: $username) {
        username
        email
    }
}
```

I've tried calling ReadUser, ReadUserQuery, readuser; nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that you added `apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'`?

Comment: Yes I did, I managed to solve it by copying the file into my main package folder. I'll add that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by copying the generated class file and pasting it into my main package folder